# Do nginx fastcgi script permissions stay with script owner or www-data (webserver user?)

Tags: permissions, nginx, fastcgi, scripting

Does the fastcgi permissions in nginx work like those in Apache, in which it runs with permissions of the script owner?

From what I see it runs with the permissions of the web user. Can it be changed to run with only the scripts owners rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes nginx fastcgi permissions stay with the script owner

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand suphp achieves this by using normal CGI instead of FastCGI which makes it far slower. There is also no nginx module that can do this. Generally Nginx isn't really suited for being used stand-alone on a shared hosting server.

Comment: I think my you misunderstood my question. But it does, given that the fastcgipass option sends the request to a socket with a script running as the script owner I would say it does.

Comment: I think you phrased your question badly then. Nginx does not work with PHP as Apache does. Apache embeds PHP within itself and the Apache user == PHP user, it can even switch to different users. With Nginx there is a fastcgi abstraction layer so the nginx user != the php user and PHP cannot switch which user it runs as. If that's not what you meant the try reformulating your question.